# Can we use Spring data redis - partialUpdate in Production env?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

I have been using partialUpdate, redisKVTemplate.update(entity) and it works well at our development environment, but when run this code in Production environment then Redis server CPU usage is high (~100%) with only several hundreds of transactions.
I have investigated bases on https://redis.io/docs/reference/optimization/latency/ and see:

- When using partialUpdate, it call many KEYS redis commands. Checked by run: redis-cli slowlog get 200 when partialUpdate is called.
- In the upper link, there is an importance note: a VERY common source of latency generated by the execution of slow commands is the use of the KEYS command in production environments. KEYS, as documented in the Redis documentation, should only be used for debugging purposes.

So does it mean partialUpdate should not use in PD env? if yes, which way should be use for partial update in PD env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/0e847a3da865481d40c353ddc8507fbe9aec2e0a/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisKeyValueAdapter.java#L399 you can see the amount of work that the `update(PartialUpdate<?> update)` is doing.

I don't know exactly where the `KEYS` commands are issued in your case but it could be related to secondary index maintenance. You could test updating the specific field in your Hashes using the `RedisHashCommands` directly. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisHashCommands.html

Mainly `hSet`, `hSetNX` and `hMSet`. In which case you will have to calculate the Redis key for your entries (using you entities IDs and the classname if you didn't use a prefix with `@RedisHash`)).

**Note**: If you are going to do multiple operations, note how the method linked above uses `RedisOperations` to ensure that everything happens over a single connection:

```
redisOps.execute((RedisCallback<Void>) connection -> { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I have checked more detail in PartialUpdate() source code and see that at 473 line: new IndexWriter(connection, converter).updateIndexes(toBytes(id), rdo.getIndexedData()); in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/0e847a3da865481d40c353ddc8507fbe9aec2e0a/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisKeyValueAdapter.java#L399. (continue in next comment)

Comment: Investigate more: updateIndexes() -> createOrUpdateIndexes() -> because the code uses PartialUpdate so removeKeyFromExistingIndexes() is called -> call a KEYS command. And at this link https://redis.io/commands/keys/ there is a note that: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. Do you any suggestion for this case?  (continue in next comment)

Comment: I am thinking about changing this KEYS command to SCAN/SETS as the note recommended, but still concern that: this is spring-data-redis source code so why they have not updated this way for a new version? still keep using KEYS command.

Comment: There is a bug (the same issue) in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/1625